# Importing structured data into python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, import

I have a text file with a set of arrays in it that looks like this:

```
[(0,1,3),(0,4,5),...(1,9,0)]

[(9,8,7),(0,4,5),...(1,9,0)]
```

where the rows are not the same length.

This is essentially a list of paths, where each set of points is a path, ie:

```
(0,1,3),(0,4,5),...(1,9,0) =path1

(9,8,7),(0,4,5),...(1,9,0) =path2
```

I need to import this in a form where I can call all elements. eg for all points in path 1, determine the distance to all points in path 2. Not sure where to start considering the delimiters don't want to hand both brackets and commas, and then built arrays in a callable way.

Comment: You can use eval on each line to create lists

Comment: Do you mean import like loading data from a file?

Comment: eval is pretty magic... let's see if I can make that work
Yeah, it a text file.

Answer (score 0):

The following code reads the data in (assuming one path per line, and no extra whitespace) into a list of numpy arrays, then demonstrates how to compute the distance between two points.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la

#replace with your datafile
datafile = "../data/point_path.txt"
paths = []
with open(datafile, "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    point_strs = line.strip().strip("[()]").split("),(")
    npoints = len(point_strs)
    path = np.empty((npoints, 3))
    for i in xrange(npoints):
      path[i,:] = np.array(map(int, point_strs[i].split(",")))
    paths.append(path)

print "First point of path 1:"
print paths[0][0]
print "Second point of path 2:"
print paths[1][1]

print "Euclidean Distance between these points:"
print la.norm(paths[0][0]-paths[1][1])
```

The output of this is:

```
First point of path 1:
[ 0.  1.  3.]
Second point of path 2:
[ 0.  4.  5.]
Euclidean Distance between these points:
3.60555127546
```

**Edit: How to format input file**
The code assumes that each list of points is on its own line (e.g. for line in f, parse list of points). So the following file:

```
[(0,2,3),(0,4,0)] [(1,4,5),(5,8,9),(3,4,0)] [(0,5,7),(0,6,8),(1,5,6),(5,8,10)]
```

will not work because all 3 lists are on the same line.

This format:

```
[(0,2,3),(0,4,0)]
[(1,4,5),(5,8,9),(3,4,0)]
[(0,5,7),(0,6,8),(1,5,6),(5,8,10)]
```

will work, as each list of points is on a separate line.

Comment: If you put each string corresponding to a path on a new line it should work.

Comment: So I testes this on
[(0,2,3),(0,4,0)]
[(1,4,5),(5,8,9),(3,4,0)]
[(0,5,7),(0,6,8),(1,5,6),(5,8,10)],
and it only spat out the last path when I did print paths or path, and it couldn't find paths[1][1]. I guess this could be something to do with each row being a different lengths...

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit thick and there is path mentioned above a good few times... what does "put each string corresponding to a path" mean code form?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my answer to explain the format my program is expecting. You did say that a "set of points is a path".